# Bash: using commands as parameters (specifically cd, dirname and find)

Tags: bash, unix, parameters, find, cd

This command and output:

```
% find . -name file.xml 2> /dev/null
./a/d/file.xml
%
```

So this command and output:

```
% dirname `find . -name file.xml 2> /dev/null`
./a/d
%
```

So you would expect that this command:

```
% cd `dirname `find . -name file.xml 2> /dev/null``
```

Would change the current directory to ./a/d.  Strangely this does not work.  When I type `cd ./a/d`.  The directory change works.  However I cannot find out why the above does not work...

Comment: the second backtick is being interpreted differently than you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just noticed the backticks... use this instead:

```
cd $(dirname $(find . -name file.xml 2> /dev/null))
```

**edit**: with the arguments quoted (in case they contain white space):

```
cd "$(dirname "$(find . -name file.xml 2> /dev/null)")"
```

Comment: Huh, that worked.  Oooo, I see it is assuming that the first two backticks are together and the second two are together.

Comment: quote your variable also for space in name problems.

Answer (score 5):

you can use `find`'s `-execdir` option as well

```
   -execdir command {} +
          Like  -exec,  but  the  specified  command  is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file, ....
```

so there's no need to `cd`

Answer (score 2):

Use the '$(...)' notation as in @fortran's answer.  If you must use back-ticks, then you have to escape the nested ones:

```
cd `dirname \`find . -name file.xml 2> /dev/null\``
```

It gets really hairy when you want to change to the lib directory for your current version of Perl, for example.

#### Easy

```
cd $(dirname $(dirname $(which perl)))/lib
```

#### Hard

```
cd `dirname \`dirname \\\`which perl\\\`\``/lib
```

That's why the '$(...)' notation is preferrable.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can write this with one less level of backticks using `find -exec`:

```
cd `find . -name file.xml -exec dirname {} \;`
```

Or alternatively using GNU find's `-printf` action:

```
cd `find . -name file.xml -printf %h`
```